# delay at logon while applying your personal settings

Tags: windows

Our application is creating a new Windows user in answer to each request. In space of one year hundred of thousands of new users are being added and subsequently deleted. We noticed that after a while our servers start to slow down while logging on a new user. The delay occurs when Windows displays "Applying your personal setting" message, taking 25 seconds on a used server as opposed to 5 seconds it takes on a brand new machine. Each time a user logs on it logs on using a brand new user account. We cleaned up the registry of any residual entries left over while adding and deleting a users but it made no difference. Is there any way to correct this problem without having to reinstall the OS?

Comment: on a "used" server how many profiles exist or are they always deleted on log off?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Start -> Computer -> Properties
Click on Advanced System Settings.  This will bring up the System Properties already on the Advanced Tab.  Click the Settings button for User Profiles. You can delete old profiles from here.

As another troubleshooting step, try this:
Run gpedit.msc and the go to Computer Config -> Admin Templates -> System
Enable verbose vs normal status messages and then reboot.
Watch the screen carefully during the boot up process.

Answer (score 0):

Look at

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

Consider deleting the entire key.

Also windows just isn't supposed to work that way, why not reuse accounts? Also I assume you mean local accounts.

Comment: Well, the registry have been thoroughly cleaned but it made no difference.

Comment: How did you clean it, there is no good registry cleaner, certainly none would dare to delete that.

Comment: We exported the registry before/after, run a diff, identified all new keys than used regedit to clean up those.

Answer (score 0):

Some well-selected folder redirection could speed things up a lot. Also, are the "used" server being taken care of with regard of file system fragmentation and correct DNS settings?

In general, I'd look through terminal server and Citrix recommendations for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Are these accounts ever re-used?  Can they be setup as roaming?

If so then you could set the `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\user profiles\delete cached copies of roaming profiles` policy to automatically delete old profiles.

If there is nothing unique about these various accounts you might also want to setup a mandatory profile that you apply to all of these accounts to help speed up the login.